# Python 2.7: Dynamic module import in an imported module based on given variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-module

There are given two versions of a storage. Based on the version, I need to select the proper interface module to get the result.

The file structure looks like this:

```
lib/
    __init__.py
    provider.py
    connection.py
    device.py

    storage/
        __init__.py
        interface_v1.py    # interface for storage of version 1
        interface_v2.py    # interface for storage of version 2

main.py
```

The `main.py` imports `provider.py`, that should import one of the interfaces listed in the `storage` subpackage depending on the version of the storage.

main.py:

```
from lib.provider import Provider
from lib.connection import Connection
from lib.device import Device

connection = Connection.establish(Device)
storage_version = Device.get_storage_version()

massage = Provider.get_data(connection)
```

provider.py should import an interface to the storage based on `storage_version` and implement provide some functions:

```
from storage import interface

class Provider(object):

    def __init_(self):
        self.storage = interface.Storage

    def get_data(self, connection):
        return self.storage.get_data()

    def clear_storage(self, connection):
        self.storage.clear_storage()
```

This example is not complete, but should be sufficient for the problem explanation.

Additional question:

- Is it possible to use `storage.__init__` to use import just the
  subpackage?
- How to proper implement Factory in Python?

Comment: What have you done to actually try to solve the problem, and what isn't working about it?

Comment: @kindall: Actually, the problem is that I do not know how to import the interface due to storage_version. The normal dynamic import does not work here, because the storage_version is defined after the provider module is imported.

Comment: What about having Provider1 and Provider2 class and use a factory or somesuch to get a corresp provider instance *after* you know storage_version?  No dynam needed that I see.

Comment: @JL Peyret: That could be the solution. Because the providers have almost the same code, I wanted to have one class, but may be they could inherit from a common base class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `interface_v1` and `interface_v2` bith impleement a class `StorageClass`I guess something like this:

```
import storage.interface_v1
import storage.interface_v2

class Provider(object):

    def __init__(self , version):
        if version == 1:
           self.storage = storage.interface_v1.StorageClass
        else:
           self.storage = storage.interface_v2.StorageClass
```

Would be the best solution - but [https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#**import**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) should provide a way to import a module based on name.

Comment: Agree too.  No need for finicky dynamic loading and you can provide for both storage versions at the same time, should you need to.